# Text Analysis in R: How to add variables to my machine learning classifier in addition to the tokens?

Tags: r, machine-learning, quanteda, machine-learning-model

## how to consider additional variables

I am working on a classification task using quanteda in R and I want to include some variables to be considered by my models apart from the bag of words.
for instance, I computed dictionary based sentiment indexes and I d like to include these variables so that the models consider them.

these are the indexes  I created, for each document.

```
dfneg <-  cbind(negDfm1@docvars$label , negDfm1@x ,posDfm@x ,  angDfm@x , 
disgDfm1@x)
colnames(dfneg) <- c("label","neg" , "pos" , "ang" , "disg")
dfneg <- as.data.frame(dfneg)
```

this is the document features matrix I will work with:

## DFM

```
newsdfm <- dfm(newscorp, tolower = TRUE , stem = FALSE ,  remove_punct = 
TRUE, remove = stopwords("english"),verbose=TRUE)
newst<- dfm_trim(newsdfm , min_docfreq=2 , verbose=TRUE)

id_train <- sample(1:6335, 5384, replace = FALSE)
# create docvar with ID
docvars(newst, "id_numeric") <- 1:ndoc(newst)

# get training set
train <- dfm_subset(newst, id_numeric %in% id_train)

# get test set (documents not in id_train)
test <- dfm_subset(newst, !id_numeric %in% id_train)
```

finally, I run a classification, for instance, a Naive Bayes classifier or lasso

## Naive Bayes classifier   or lasso

```
NBmodel <- textmodel_nb(train , train@docvars$label)


lasso <- cv.glmnet(train, train@docvars$label, 
family="binomial", alpha=1, nfolds=10,
type.measure="class")
```

this is what I tried after creating the dfm, but it didn't work

```
 newsdfm@Dimnames$features$negz <- dfneg$neg
 newsdfm@Dimnames$features$posz <- dfneg$pos
 newsdfm@Dimnames$features$angz <- dfneg$ang
 newsdfm@Dimnames$features$disgz <- dfneg$disg
```

then I thought of creating document variables before creating newsdfm

```
   docvars(newscorp , "negz") <- dfneg$neg
   docvars(newscorp , "posz") <- dfneg$pos
   docvars(newscorp , "angz") <- dfneg$ang
   docvars(newscorp , "disgz") <- dfneg$disg
```

but at that point, I don't know how to tell the classifier that I want it to consider also these document variables in addition to the bag of words.

In summary, I expect the model to consider both the matrix with all the words per each document and the indexes I created per each document.

any suggestion is highly appreciated

thank you in advance,

Carlo

Comment: Did you look at the [tutorial for naive bayes](https://tutorials.quanteda.io/machine-learning/nb/)? I think your question is already pretty much covered there. If not, could you provide a working reproducible example? I don't know where your `newscorp` object is coming from an can't reproduce any errors.

Comment: well, it does the classification only using the features of the documents, while I want also to use new variables as explanatory variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, dfm are sparse matrices, but it is better to avoid manipulating them directly if possible.

For adding new features for `textmodel_nb()`, you need to add them to the dfm. As you might expect, the easiest way to do so is to use `cbind()` to dfm.

In your example, you can run something like this:

```r
additional_features <- dfneg[, c("neg", "pos", "ang", "disg")] %>% as.matrix()
newsdfm_added <- cbind(newsdfm, additional_features)
```

As you see, I firstly created a matrix of additional features and then run `cbind()`. When you execute `cbind()` you will get the following warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: cbinding dfms with different docnames 
2: cbinding dfms with overlapping features will result in duplicated features
```

As this indicates you have to make sure that the colnames for the additional features should not be in the original dfm.